# Showing compilation error when I tried to call setDataEnabled from system app

Tags: android

I am working on Launcher app, I used setDataEnabled() of TelephonyManager to enable the data.

It is showing compilation error when I tried to call **setDataEnabled()**.

```
TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if (tm != null) {

boolean curState = tm.getDataEnabled();
    tm.setDataEnabled(curState ? false : true);

}
```

The same code is present in SetupWizard, it's working fine. In order to work in Launcher, will we need modify Android.mk file ?
How it make it work for system app ?

Thanks ...

Comment: Any idea about this query 
Thanks !!

Comment: This API is working perfectly in Test app, I hope that this issue is induced in my Launcher app due to some changes of Android.mk file. I'll share my Android.mk if required.